# How to connect two windows PC which uses same Router for internet but one is connected via wired LAN and another is on Wi-Fi?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, wireless-router, file-sharing

I use DIR-555 Dlink router for Internet for my laptops and Desktop. My laptop is on Wi-Fi but my desktop is connected to Router via wired LAN. Internet works fine on both.

I want to share a Desktop folder with my Laptop to watch my videos files on laptop. Is it possible? If yes then how

**My OS in both is Windows 7**

[image]

Comment: both are on the same subnet, you can share using Homegroup. Medium(wired/wireless) doesn't matter, since you're on the same subnet, it should be fine

Comment: @Sathya - I got stuck on this screen after I enabled Homegroup. http://i.imgur.com/yaGdwHZ.png don't which password is this asking. I have tried my wi-fi password, windows login password and homegroup password. none of these is working

Answer (score 1):

When you first created your Homegroup, Windows would have made you pick a password for it.  I would assume you set up the Homegroup on your desktop.  So, why not [just "change" the password there for the Homegroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-a-homegroup-password)?  I'll put the instructions here, but there's a nice video at the link.

> To change a homegroup password
>
> - Open HomeGroup by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control Panel**, typing **homegroup** in the search box, and then clicking **HomeGroup**.
> - Click **Change the password**, and then click **Change the password**.
> - Type the new password you want to use (or accept the suggested one), click **Next**, and then click **Finish**.

At that point, you should have no issues connecting to your Homegroup, and accessing your designated shared/public directories.